# What do you call this play on words?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Last night I was watching T.V.  and there was a TV commercial about a show named

> Stand Parados

I know `Stand` in Spanish could mean "Parado/a/os/as" as a noun eg:

```
They are stand
```

could mean:

```
Están Parados
```

so `Stand` sounds like `Están`, so I think that's the reason why the show uses `Stand` instead of `Están`.

So what do you call this play on words?

Comment: *They are stand* no tiene sentido. *They are standing* significa *Están de pie*. En cuánto al título ese, [se trata de comedia *stand-up*](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/STANDparados), o sea la que se hace delante de una audiencia contando anécdotas y a veces interactuando con ellos. Lo que habría que preguntar es qué pinta *Parados* en el título.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, If you edit that part the question it's hard to understand what the OP is trying to say, because standing is not similar to Están.

Comment: @syrux, it's certainly hard to understand what OP is trying to say. Perhaps I haven't been explicit enough in what *I'm* trying to say, which is that I don't think there's much evidence for a play on words in the first place, so there's not much point in trying to classify it.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, agree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### False cognate

False cognates are pairs of words in the same or **different languages** that are similar in form and pronunciation but have different roots and meaning.

Additional information:

- Making some research I discovered that Wikipedia has a wrong definition of False Cognate (my definition was never extracted from Wkipedia).
- My answer is only applicable if you compare the two words not the whole sentence (which is misspelled)

Answer (score 7):

**[Pun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun) or [paronomasia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paronomasia)** (in your case, with false friends words)

The pun, also called paronomasia, is a form of word play that suggests two or more meanings, by exploiting multiple meanings of words, or of similar-sounding words, for an intended humorous or rhetorical effect.